# Jade, Why variables are sent in single quotes in one case and unquoted in another?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, pug

I put some data from MongoDB into a Jade template as simple as this:

```
  span(data-id=job._id)
  span= job._id
```

But for some reason I get first span int the output HTML markup looking like `<span data-id="'5188b71aaeacb0c503000002'"></span>` while second span looks better - `<span>5188b71aaeacb0c503000002</span>`.

Why in first case single quotes are added there?

Comment: should not be. Are you sure it's not quoted on your end?

Answer (score 0):

I have been unable to get two diferent values from `job._id` .

**TEST 1:**

passing: `{"job": {"_id": "hello"}}`

your jade:

```
span(data-id=job._id)
span= job._id
```

Html output:

```
<span data-id="hello"></span>    <-- No extra ''
<span>hello</span>
```

**TEST 2:**

passing: `{"job": {"_id": "'hello'"}} <-- extra ''`

the jade:

```
span(data-id=job._id)
span #{job._id}       // or  span= job._id
```

Html output:

```
<span data-id="'hello'"></span>
<span>'hello'</span>
```